# Ignore property with automap IF something

Tags: automapper

first time using automap and I want to do something like

```
public class Destination{
 pulic int Id {get;Set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public string Age{get;set;}
}

if(something)
 var x = Mapping.Mapper.Map<Destination>(object) (with all properties)
else
 var y = Mapping.Mapper.Map<Destination>(object) (without Age property)
```

It's a dummy example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Ignore()` feature to strict members you will never map but these members are will be skipped in configuration validation.

What you might find usefull to use is the [Condition()](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html) feature so you can map the member when the condition is true like the example below:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
   cfg.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.baz, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.baz >= 0)));
 });
```

In the above mapping example the property baz will only be mapped if it is greater than or equal to 0 in the source object.